# Ionic - Understanding Lazy Loading

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Working with ionic 3 I am finally implementing lazy loading into my apps. I have a theoretical question on performance which applies to both Ionic 3/4.

Hypothetically say I have 3 pages:

**Page1**

**Page2**

**Page3**

all of which are lazy loaded.

In addition say I have a modal page called:

**ModalPage**

This modal page is size 1.5mb.

Assume ModalPage is used in Page 1 and Page 2 and included in the respective module.ts for each page (not in app.module).

My question is:

1. When I load the app and I open page1 first and then push page 2 onto the stack. As ModalPage is not global and imported separately for page 1 and page 2. Does this mean my app when I open page1 will lazy-load & download the 1.5mb Modal Page  and then again another instance of modal page @ 1.5mb when I push page 2 onto the stack? So in total I am downloading 3mb worth of code?
2. If above is true apart from downloading issues is there any other impact on performance? ie having multiple instances of components/pages loaded via page modules vs globally importing the component/pages into the app.module

Comment: It should only be downloaded once

Comment: 3. *"this modal page is size 1.5mb"*. why ? how is that acceptable for mobile app ?

Comment: It is a theoretical question not a real world example, just trying to understand how best to strategise lazy loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an ionic 3 app that is lazy loading (not using app.module), with a component used in multiple pages.  I've never checked the loading pattern, so I fired up a dev instance to check.

**Sources Tab**
If you look at the `Sources` tab in dev tools, for a debug build (with sourcemaps) you will see at initial load time the shared component isn't loaded at all.  Then once I hit a page that needs the component it loads into the standard `components` directory (when using a debug build, anyway).  Hitting a second page that also uses this component doesn't load a second instance of it or anything (in the `Sources` tab).

**Network Tab**
If you do the same activity, but look at the `Network` tab, it's not quite as clear.  Once you hit that first page that uses the shared component, in my case the file `11.js` was requested.  Looking at that file, it clearly had the typescript of the shared component in it.  I then hit the second page that uses this component, and (in my case) `18.js` was downloaded, and it, too, had the typescript of the shared component in it.

Based on this, my impression is that a debug build is downloading the typescript of the shared component multiple times (once per page that needs it).  Not sure if a prod build or any other factors would change that result.

Comment: Thanks Brass so in short your obvservation is once a component is used in one page it doesn't re-download that component and instead re-uses the component if needed another page? If so this is a good thing.

Comment: Sort of.  Please see some updates I am making to my answer shortly.